# How to center the entry of a multicolumn in an array?

Tags: multicolumn, arrays

I want to make the center of `\fbox{$1+4=5$}` be horizontally aligned with the `\uparrow`. However, it seems that the following code does not work (see the figure below). BTW, is it possible to replace `*{3}{c@{\quad\quad}}` with `*{3}{c@{\enspace}}` and still make the center of `\fbox{$1+4=5$}` be horizontally aligned with the `\uparrow`? I would appreciate your help with this situation.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c@{\quad} *{3}{c@{\quad\quad}}}
        &   & 3         & 6     \\
\times  &   &           & 7     \\ \hline
        & 2 & 5         & 2     \\
        &   & \uparrow  &       \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\fbox{$1+4=5$}} 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to put it in the same column as 5 and the arrow, `\framebox[0pt]{$1+4=5$}` ?  and not use multicolumn at all? (otherwise just use the same `@{..}` as in the main tabular specification.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Doesn't this screw up the frame of the framebox?

Comment: Although this slightly alters the spaces between the columns as compared to the original, the following should center the framebox correctly: `\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1em}
\begin{array}{*{4}{c}}
        &   & 3         & 6     \\
\times  &   &           & 7     \\ \hline
        & 2 & 5         & 2     \\
        &   & \uparrow  &       \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\fbox{$1+4=5$}} 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}`

Comment: @leandriis er perhaps makebox[0pt] around an fbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're forgetting that the template has `c@{\quad\quad}`

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c@{\quad} *{3}{c@{\quad\quad}}}
        &   & 3         & 6     \\
\times  &   &           & 7     \\ \hline
        & 2 & 5         & 2     \\
        &   & \uparrow  &       \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{c@{\quad\quad}}{\boxed{1+4=5}} 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, the centering is not perfect, due to the asymmetry in column spacing and you can fix it by adding some negative space to compensate:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c@{\quad} *{3}{c@{\quad\quad}}}
        &   & 3         & 6     \\
\times  &   &           & 7     \\ \hline
        & 2 & 5         & 2     \\
        &   & \uparrow  &       \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{c@{\quad\quad}}{\hspace{-0.5em}\boxed{1+4=5}} 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the simplest way is to center it with a zero width box:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c@{\quad} *{3}{c@{\quad\quad}}}
        &   & 3         & 6     \\
\times  &   &           & 7     \\ \hline
        & 2 & 5         & 2     \\
        &   & \uparrow  &       \\
        &   & \makebox[0pt]{$\boxed{1+4=5}$} 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With use of the `w{c}{2em}` for the last three columns:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{array}{c *{3}{w{c}{2em}} }
        &   & 3         & 6     \\
\times  &   &           & 7     \\ \hline
        & 2 & 5         & 2     \\
        &   & \uparrow  &   \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{@{} c @{}}{\fbox{$1+4=5$}}
\end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]